# Meteor method defined in lib, can't be found under server/lib

Tags: meteor

I have a Method defined in *lib/methods.js*:

```
Meteor.methods({
    getTask: function( extraparam ) {
        return {dummy: 'dummy'};
    }
});
```

But when I call it from *server/lib/environment.js*:

```
Meteor.call( "getTask", extraparam );
```

I'm getting *Method not found*, I was under the impression *lib/* is loaded before *server/lib*, 
 or should I call the method in *server/main.js* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to this issue, the load order rules work as follows:

1. Paths containing lib gain priority.
2. Paths gain priority based on their depth.

Combining the two shows us that `/server/lib/x.js` will be loaded before `/lib/x.js`. With methods this shouldn't be an issue unless the method is invoked as soon as the containing file is executed.

Your options are:

1. Fix the load order by moving the call as you suggested. `main.js` will be loaded last so this will work.
2. Call the method from within a [Meteor.startup](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_startup) callback.

Comment: Very good clarification, I'd like to add that I ended up calling the method on server/main.js , it's also a more logical place to put that in